# How to add mysql connector jar file in classpath in suse 15 Jenkins Java 11

Tags: java, mysql, jenkins, sles

I am running this (code below) groovy snippet to connect to MySQL from Jenkins, and hitting the issue below. I have already checked all the questions here and also referred other links in Google but not able to find the exact solution for this particular environment. My Jenkins is deployed in a SUSE 15 client with java 11.
(**Please read the entire question before marking duplicate**) :

Issue -

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Full Error Stack -

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:476)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:589)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:511)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:315)
at groovy.sql.Sql.loadDriver(Sql.java:738)
at groovy.sql.Sql.newInstance(Sql.java:465)
at groovy.sql.Sql$newInstance.call(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:152)
at Script1.run(Script1.groovy:3)
at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:574)
at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:612)
at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.evaluate(GroovyShell.java:583)
at hudson.util.RemotingDiagnostics$Script.call(RemotingDiagnostics.java:149)
at hudson.util.RemotingDiagnostics$Script.call(RemotingDiagnostics.java:118)
at hudson.remoting.LocalChannel.call(LocalChannel.java:47)
at hudson.util.RemotingDiagnostics.executeGroovy(RemotingDiagnostics.java:115)
at jenkins.model.Jenkins._doScript(Jenkins.java:4729)
at jenkins.model.Jenkins.doScript(Jenkins.java:4700)
at java.base/java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle.invokeWithArguments(MethodHandle.java:710)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$MethodFunction.invoke(Function.java:397)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$InstanceFunction.invoke(Function.java:409)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvoke(Function.java:207)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvokeAndServeResponse(Function.java:140)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$11.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:558)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:59)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:762)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:894)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:690)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:240)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:764)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$ChainEnd.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1665)
at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:157)
at jenkins.security.ResourceDomainFilter.doFilter(ResourceDomainFilter.java:81)
at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:154)
at jenkins.telemetry.impl.UserLanguages$AcceptLanguageFilter.doFilter(UserLanguages.java:129)
at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:154)
at jenkins.metrics.impl.MetricsFilter.doFilter(MetricsFilter.java:125)
at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:154)
at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:160)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:202)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1635)
at hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:154)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:202)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1635)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:94)
at jenkins.security.AcegiSecurityExceptionFilter.doFilter(AcegiSecurityExceptionFilter.java:52)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:99)
at hudson.security.UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.doFilter(UnwrapSecurityExceptionFilter.java:54)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:99)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:122)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:116)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:99)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:109)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:99)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:106)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:97)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:99)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:223)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:217)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:99)
at jenkins.security.BasicHeaderProcessor.doFilter(BasicHeaderProcessor.java:97)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:99)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:112)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:82)
at hudson.security.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.java:63)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:99)
at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:111)
at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:172)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:202)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1635)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:53)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:202)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1635)
at hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:86)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:202)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1635)
at org.kohsuke.stapler.DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.doFilter(DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.java:30)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:202)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1635)
at jenkins.security.SuspiciousRequestFilter.doFilter(SuspiciousRequestFilter.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:202)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1635)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:527)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:131)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:549)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:122)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:223)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1571)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:221)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1378)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:176)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:484)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1544)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:174)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1300)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:129)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:122)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:562)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$0(HttpChannel.java:505)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:762)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:497)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:282)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:319)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:100)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectableChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectableChannelEndPoint.java:53)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.runTask(AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.java:412)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.consumeTask(AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.java:381)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.tryProduce(AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.java:268)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.lambda$new$0(AdaptiveExecutionStrategy.java:138)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:407)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:894)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:1038)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

Code -

```
import java.sql.*; 
import groovy.sql.Sql

sql = Sql.newInstance('jdbc:mysql://<ip>:<port>/<db>?serverTimezone=UTC', 
     '<user>', '<pass>', 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver')
```

Jenkins version - **Jenkins 2.361.4**

Java version -

```
jenkinsclient01:/usr/share/java # java -version
openjdk version "11.0.16" 2022-07-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.16+8-suse-150000.3.83.1-x8664)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.16+8-suse-150000.3.83.1-x8664, mixed mode)
```

Java class Path -

```
System.getProperty("java.class.path")
Result: /usr/share/java/jenkins.war
```

I have also done

```
zypper install mysql-connector-java
```

Also tried (got it from Google search) -

```
java cp ~/mysql-connector-java-8.0.30.jar /usr/share/java/jenkins.war Main
```

this throwing error -

```
jenkinsclient01:/usr/share/java # java -cp ~/mysql-connector-java-8.0.30.jar /usr/share/java/jenkins.war Main
Error: Could not find or load main class .usr.share.java.jenkins.war
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: /usr/share/java/jenkins/war
```

Question - How to add the mysql connector jar file in this scenario to correct the error?

I don't know Java. Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

Add the jdbc drivers under `${JENKINS_HOME}/war/WEB-INF/lib`.

I also had to copy the same jdbc jar file under the `--webroot` directory which from my understanding acts as a local cache for `.WAR` extraction.

Remove the `Main` from the run command; it's not required and results to the following error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class .usr.share.java.jenkins.war
```

You should end up with a command similar to the following:

```
java -jar /usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war --webroot=/var/cache/jenkins/war
```

In my case I also had to Approve a number of in-process scripts before I got the database connections working.